# Finding the nth instance of a pattern match using regex

Tags: java, regex

Given the String:

```
<td>4</td><td>punz of damage</td><td><img src='images/no.png'></img></td><td>May 26, 2015 10:28:12 PM</td><td>30</td><td>Nov 26, 2017 10:28:12 PM</td>
```

I would like to be able to return only the value between the second  element.

How would I accomplish this? I have the following so far:

```
    private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<td>(.+?)</td>");

public static String getName(String in) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    if (m.matches()) {
        return m.group(1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using regexes on html. use a DOM parser. xpath makes this sort of thing beyond trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matcher.find()` in a loop instead of `matches` and keep a counter:

```
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<td>(.+?)</td>");

public static String getName(String in) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    for (i=0; i<1 && m.find(); i++);

    if (i==0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return m.group(1);
    }
}
```

**Caution:** Parsing HTML/XML using regex can be error prone.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be an easy way of accomplishing what I needed. I believe it's time I take another crack and reading over the documentation and understanding it.